# No puedo eliminar un solo item, se me borran todos, pero las otras funciones, get post y put me funcionan bien, no se donde esterá el error

Tags: nodejs, express, router

No puedo eliminar un solo item, se me borran todos, pero las otras funciones, get post y put me funcionan bien, no se donde esterá el error

```
export default class Api{
    constructor(rutaBD){
        this.rutaBD = rutaBD;
    }
async findAll(){
        try {
            const todos = await fs.promises.readFile(this.rutaBD, 'utf-8')
            return JSON.parse(todos)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error : ${error}`)
        }
    }
async deleteById(id){
        try {
            const all = await this.findAll()
            let result = all.find(e=>e.id==id)
            if(result){
                const newArray = all.filter(producto=>producto.id ==! id);
                await fs.promises.writeFile(this.rutaBD, JSON.stringify(newArray))
                return newArray 
            }else{
                 console.log("Producto no encontrado")
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

en otro archivo tengo

```
import { Router } from "express";
import Api from "../apiClass";
const router = Router()
const api = new Api("./src/dataBase/productos.json")

router.delete('/:id', async(req,res)=>{
    const {id} = req.params
    await api.deleteById(id)
    res.send("producto eliminado")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes un error de tipeo que hace mal la condicion del filter

```
const newArray = all.filter(producto=>producto.id ==! id);
```

cambia el `==!` por `!==`

```
const newArray = all.filter(producto=>producto.id !== id);
```

> Finalmente, como el comparador `!==` compara valor y ademas el tipo, podrias asegurarte que tu `id` que viaja como parametro en la ruta sea siempre del tipo de dato que vos necesitas, haciendo algo como esto

```
router.delete('/:id', async(req,res)=>{
    const {id} = req.params
    const newId = String(id)  // Esto si necesitas que ID sea de tipo string
    const newId = parseInt(id) // O esto otro si necesitas que viaje un numero
    await api.deleteById(newId)
    res.send("producto eliminado")
})
```

> Otra forma seria asegurar el tipo, ya una vez dentro de la funcion eliminar:

```
async deleteById(id){
     const newId = String(id)  // Esto si necesitas que ID sea de tipo string
     const newId = parseInt(id) // O esto otro si necesitas que viaje un numero
      try {
            const all = await this.findAll()
            let result = all.find(e=>e.id==newId)
            if(result){
                const newArray = all.filter(producto=>producto.id ==! newId);
```

Comment: No no, lo cambie pero tampoco me funciona

Comment: Raro, porque probe en consola agarrar un array y meterle [1,2,3,4,5], despues filtre un elemento con !==, y otra vez con ==! y me paso lo mismo que te pasa a vos, el resultado del filter con el comparador ``==!`` es un array vacio, lo que haria parecer que se eliminaron todas las entradas. Te diria que borres cache y lo pruebes una vez mas jaja, pero bueno, tal vez sea otra cosa...

Comment: @DiegoRios si tiras un console dentro del ``if(result){``, llega bien el id hasta ahi?

Comment: let newArray = todos.filter(producto=>producto.id !== id);
Esa línea de código me trae todo el array, no me borra el ítem con el id que indico

Comment: Si llega bien l
et newArray = todos.filter(producto=>producto.id !== id);
console.log(newArray)
Me trae el array completo, no me elimina el que yo paso por id

Comment: @DiegoRios Bueno, entonces vamos bien, el operador al principio te devolvia el array vacio. Ahora no esta filtrando el Array pero al parecer la comparacion esta bien. Tene en cuenta que estas comparando ``!==`` y este comparador no solo compara valor, sino tambien el tipo. Podrias consolear ``typeof(el.id)`` y ``typeof(id)`` para asegurarte que sean el mismo tipo. Si no lo son, podes convertir el que haga falta o solo comparar con ``!=``, que compara el valor pero no el tipo.

Comment: No entendi muy bien eso de typoof(el.id), pero console.log(typeof(id))  me tira string

Comment: Bien, imaginate que tengo dos valores: ``a = 12`` y ``b="12"``, en la variable ``a`` el type es Number, mientras que en ``b`` el type es String. Si los comparas mediante ``a === b`` el resultado va a ser false, porque si bien el valor es el mismo (12), el tipo de dato es diferente. En cambio, si comparas ``a == b`` el resultado va a ser true. Cuando queres comparar que dos valores sean DIFERENTES, ``!==`` compara tambien el tipo de dato, mientras que ``!=`` solo compara el valor.

Comment: @DiegoRios en tu caso comparas ``producto=>producto.id !== id``,  imaginate que los ``id`` en los productos son de tipo Number, pero vos estas enviando un ``id`` de tipo String, esa comparacion va a dar TRUE siempre, entonces va a meter todos los elementos en el Array resultante. Por ello sospecho que si haces ``!=`` en lugar de ``!==`` deberia funcionar. No obstante te recomiendo que le cambies el tipo de dato al ``id`` que llega por parametro, para que sean el mismo tipo de dato ambos y puedas comparar con ``!==``, que es una mejor práctica.

Comment: Perfecto, tanto != como !== Number (id) me funciono, muchas graciass! mi pregunta es porque en todas las peticiones anteriores que las hice igual que esta me lo tomo como numero, y solo en esta como string

Comment: @DiegoRios la verdad que no estoy seguro, pero lo que podrias hacer es luego de esta linea ``const {id}=req.params``, si necesitas que el ``id`` sea un string haces ``id=String(id)``, y si necesitas que sea un numero entero, podes hacer ``id= parseInt(id)``. Con eso deberias asegurarte que el tipo sea el que vos necesitas, y podrias comparar con ``!==``

Comment: Muchas gracias Agustin, lo pude solucionar, pero con !=, porque la linea id= parseInt(id). me tira un error en la terminar **id is read only**, de todas maneras ya se cual es error al menos, muchisimas gracias

Comment: @DiegoRios ahi te agregue en el codigo de la respuesta las dos cosas que podrias intentar para asegurar el tipo de dato. O lo haces en el router, o lo haces en la funcion deleteById, y solo debes usar una de las opciones que te di, o lo pasas a String o lo pasas a Int. Si vos haces un ``console.log( typeof(producto.id))`` vas a saber el tipo de dato que guarda tu objeto producto en la propiedad ID, entonces ese seria el tipo de dato que necesitas

Comment: @DiegoRios ese ultimo error de ``id is read only`` es porque no podes modificar una constante, mala mia, podes declarar una nueva variable como ``const newId = parseInt(id)``, y luego haces ``await api.deleteById(newId)``, o simplemente en ``const {id} = req.params`` reemplaza const por let, para que sea una variable. No estoy seguro, pero creo que deberia funcionar.

Comment: Asi es, es porque era const jaja, se nota que soy nuevo no? muchas gracias Agustin, solucionado